# How do I access the greatest hits (questions) via API v2.2.?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, questions

The greatest hits (questions) of any stack exchange site (say stack overflow) can be found by visiting the below URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits

I would want to access these questions via an API Call using version 2.2.

Currently if I need to access any question of any stack exchange site, I use something like:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/22483974?site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody

Is this even possible to access greatest hits?

Comment: Currently not possible. Seems like it should be easy enough to add to [the `site` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site).  You *might* be able to roughly approximate this list using SEDE queries.